Replacing old theromost with 6 wires
We have an old thermostat that runs our heating and cooling (a geothermal system). I'd like to replace this thermostat with something more modern but I'm having trouble figuring out what is compatible. The Nest E thermostat doesn't have terminals for all of these wires. What is the name of the type of thermostat that I should look for? Are there specific models that I can try?
Note: I verified that all 6 wires are connected to the system. The wiring diagram is below.




To answer this question you must find the other end of the cable shown here (the furnace or the logic board controlling it), see where each of the wires is connected at that end, determine the model of equipment it is connected to, find the documentation for it, post all the details.  Judging by this photo alone, you may have 3-stage heating.   Probably not?  Your old thermostat may have done clever tricks with the W1 and X terminals?  Or they may not be connected to anything at the other end. We need to know the functionality required by your new thermostat.

Ok great -- I just added the wiring diagram. The 6 wires are just all wired into the same place in a line without labels.

Ok, and presumably the orange and white wires are connected at the furnace to W1 and W2, and the jumper is removed, as in the right diagram?   And where is the brown X wire connected?  It is for "auxiliary heat" ... IE, a different heater for when this one can't cope.  Do you have that?

I've added the only other photo I have -- I am not sure if this helps

Can you redo the last picture so the letters can be seen and so we can clearly see all the wires coming out of the brown cable, better lit so we can match their colors to the first pic and not confuse them with other wires not from the cable?  Or write it:  yellow goes to W1 etc.

Yes last picture updated

Ok, some puzzling things.   The furnace is clearly capable of two-stage operation.  But the white W1 wire from the thermostat is not connected and not visible.  You need to find that, at the furnace end and to see if the W1-W2 jumper noted on the diagram is installed or not.   Also puzzling, there is a G1 terminal, usually used for fan speed control but here on the diagram it says to use it with  fan rely, which I don't understand because every fan uses a relay, and also you have TWO green wires at the furnace.  So there is more going on here than you have documented.

This may be too hard to diagnose by internet.  You should find the manual for the furnace and someone with experience with this model.  IT should be possible to use a new smart thermostat but you need to understand the furnace better.

And .... we still don't know where the black X wire goes.  I don't necessarily expect it here at the furnace, but you need to know if it controls some alternate heating device you have so that your new stat can do that too.   Again ... there is a brown-sheathed cable that goes from the thermostat to somewhere around the furnace.  Find it, and document where every wire in it goes to including ones that are not connected.  You're missing black and white and you have an extra red, blue, and green.

Can you post photos of the actual wiring at the air handler please?

Do you think there could be a problem with the current wiring that is impacting the system? Or if I just get a new programmable thermostat with the correct terminals, it should be swappable?

According to some Google advertising, the "second and third generation Nest Learning Thermostats" are capable of controlling systems with two-stage and auxiliary heating.
So far you've shown that you have two-stage heating.   Your furnace accepts thermostat commands for W1 and W2.  You may also have a separate auxiliary system.  Usually this is baseboard or other heat to supplement your two-stage furnace on the coldest days.  So you should get a thermostat with the ability to control those.
You don't have to.  Your furnace can easily be turned into a single-stage one, with the jumper as shown on the left side of the wiring diagram.  Then you can use almost any thermostat.  But you lose efficiency and comfort if you do that.  To take full advantage, get a good thermostat.
I can't give you a list of exactly which thermostats from which brands can do 2 stage with or without Auxiliary heat.   Also, WHAT they do with those varies.   The furnace provides the ability to heat the house with different levels of power, sometimes with entirely different systems, at different efficiencies.   The thermostat decides when and how to use those different things.
Nest Learning thermostats provide reasonable documentation about how they go about it. Something like (don't quote me) if the house is 3 degrees below target it will use stage 2, if it is 7 degrees below target it will use stage 3 or auxiliary, and it will also learn the response times of the house and will back off using higher stages if the first stage can be expected to heat the house fast enough.
That sounds pretty awesome to me ... but ... they cost like $300.
You really have to get deep into the documentation to understand how a thermostat will control YOUR specific system given ITS specific abilities.
